# Click event not being bound when added in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am dragging an li element, and dropping it to ul. I want to register click handler for this li element.

However, click event is not being fired.

```
            function initListClickEvent() {
                $("#list1 > li").click(function () {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
                    $(this).css("color", "white");
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(initListClickEvent);

            $(function () {
                $("#list1").droppable({
                    accept: 'li',
                    drop: function (e, ui) {
                        initListClickEvent();
                    }
                });
            })
```

What would be the solution to the problem? All the elements react on click (because their click event has been registered previously), except the one I have just dragged to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it like

```
 function initListClickEvent() {
     $("#list1 > li").click(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        $(this).css("color", "white");
    });
        $("#list1 > li").trigger("click");
    }

    $(document).ready(initListClickEvent);

    $(function () {
        $("#list1").droppable({
            accept: 'li',
            drop: function (e, ui) {
                initListClickEvent();
            }
        });
    });
```

**Edit**

If the elements are adding dynamically, 
you should use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

```
$(document).on("click","#list1 > li",function(){
   $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        $(this).css("color", "white");
});
```

It helps you to attach handlers for the future elements

Comment: event delegation is indeed the solution. Thanks!

Comment: trigger() part is not what I need though.

Comment: no worries, maybe just remove it for future reference. Also, in this case, this event registration that I did on drop is not needed at all. Now I get it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

you should use delegate of jquery for dynamically added items

```
 $(function () {
            $("#list1").droppable({
                accept: 'li'
            });

$( "#list1" ).delegate( "li", "click", function() {
$(this).css("background-color", "blue");
$(this).css("color", "white");    });

});
```